# Date Range in Three Textbox using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have three textboxes I use datepicker for all three textboxes. When user enter 
some date in first textbox than second textbox allows the user only greater than date from the first textbox and third textbox allows the date greater than second textbox date. and If user enter the date in third textbox than the second textbox allows the date less than third textbox and first textbox allows the date less than second textbox and if the user enter the date in second textbox than the first textbox allows the date less than second textbox and third textbox allows the date greater than second textbox.

Comment: The description sounds OK (apart from missing punctuations). It will be helpful if you provide details regarding - What is your question? What have you tried till now AND what is the problem you are facing with you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ( [maxDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate) and [minDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate) ) in [onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) callback.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbHVs/2/).

I hope this helps!